# OData Source in SSIS package getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, odata

I have an SSIS package that has a single OData source (sharepoint site source). The package runs fine from Visual Studio. Once deployed to a SQL instance I try to run the package via an Agent Job (uses the Agent service account to execute), and I get the following:

```
SharePoint List to Stage:Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.Http.HttpWebRequestWrapper.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.Http.WebRequestHelper.GetResponseWithThreadSafeRetry(IWebRequest& request, 
Func`1 createWebRequest, Int32 retryCount, Int32 retrySleepInMilliseconds, Boolean isOAuth, Func`2 refreshRequestWithNewAccessToken, Func`2 
getStatusCode)
at
Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.Http.WebRequestHelper.GetResponseWithThreadSafeRetryAndImpersonation(IWebRequest&
request, DataFeedConnection connection, Func`1 createWebRequest)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.DataFeedCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.ODataSource.GetSchemaTable()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.ODataSource.PreExecute()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

The service account running the package has Full Control permissions on the SharePoint list in question. I have several other packages on the same server that use OData feed from the same SharePoint farm with the same service account without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that the error was on the SharePoint server... the lookup column threshold in Central Admin was set to 8 (the default), but the number of lookup columns in the list exceeds that. Since I'm a farm admin, I bypass the restriction. I just wish that the error that goes through to SSIS was a little more explanatory than just (500).